# chrome extension: desktop notification from a background script

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I tried to modified the original notification sample and I found that the old webit notification does not work any more.So I changed to chrome notification. Basically, I still reuse the background page like this:

```
"permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "http://*/*" 
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"], "persistent": false },
```

Any the background.js is just like this:

```
console.log("Before create " + notID + " notification");
chrome.notifications.create("id"+notID++, options, creationCallback);


function creationCallback(ID) {
  console.log("Succesfully created " + ID + " notification");
}
```

Looks like something is not configured right and I cannot see the notification. And I see the following log:

```
Before create 0 notification background.js:87
Succesfully created undefined notification background.js:92
```

Anything do I still miss here?

Thanks

Update: Here is the modified background.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var opt = {
    iconUrl: "48.png",
    type: 'list',
    title: 'Primary Title',
    message: 'Primary message to display',
    priority: 1,
    items: [{ title: 'Item1', message: 'This is item 1.'},
            { title: 'Item2', message: 'This is item 2.'},
            { title: 'Item3', message: 'This is item 3.'}]
  };
  chrome.notifications.create('notify1', opt, function() { console.log('created!');console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)});
});
```

Here is the completed manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Notification Demo",
  "version": "1.1",
  "description":
    "Shows off desktop notifications, which are \"toast\" windows that pop up on the desktop.",
  "icons": {"16": "16.png", "48": "48.png", "128": "128.png"},
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "http://*/*" 
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "manifest_version": 2,

  // crbug.com/134315
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "48.png"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You missed to include your notification options in the question. Probably there is an error there, and it doesn't get spawned. You can check `chrome.runtime.lastError` inside the callback, too.

Comment: On a side note, a direct descendant of WebkitNotifications is the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification).

Comment: I have updated with options. I see 48.png in network so the icon should be good. The last error is unknown error. Object {message: "Unknown error."}.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Notification API I may try it too.

Comment: This is really strange, as your minimal example works for me.

Comment: I changed to Notification API. It is so simple, cross browsers, and works well. Thanks Xan. So I decided to forget about chrome*_^only solution.

Comment: Considering that this situation was not reproduced, consider deleting this question; it's going to be left open and unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely there's an error going on if anything. We've recently started logging errors for unchecked chrome.runtime.lastError so try on a newer version of Chrome perhaps.

Comment: Can you say more specifically what you mean by "logging errors for unchecked `chrome.runtime.lastError`"?